# How to match text between special characters inside differents scenarios

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings in differents scenarios. The idea, is to take the text in the middle of the sentence between `||`. If there is only one `||`, will take the first part.

Examples:

> Useless information|| basic information|| advanced information|| super information|| no information

Should match: **basic information** and **advanced information** and **super information**

> Useless information|| basic information|| advanced information|| no information

Should match: **basic information** and **advanced information**

> Useless information|| basic information|| no information

Should match: **basic information**

> Useless information|| no information

Should match: **Usless information**

I have tried:

```
||[^||]*||[^||]*
```

and this one:

```
([^||]*)(?=||)
```

but does not works as expected in all scenarios. It is possible to do it with only one `regex` expression?

Comment: Maybe something like `^((?:(?!\|{2}).)*)\|{2}(?!.*\|{2})|\|{2}\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\|{2})`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/m24t5B/1).

Comment: Yeah this works. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: And also, if you can explain it, could be better :)

Comment: You should split with  `||`, it is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You might do this without a regex and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `||`

```js
const strings = [
  "Useless information|| basic information|| advanced information|| super information|| no information",
  "Useless information|| basic information|| advanced information|| no information",
  "Useless information|| basic information|| no information",
  "Useless information|| no information"
];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  let parts = s.split("||");
  let result = [];
  if (parts.length === 2) {
    result.push(parts[0]);
  }
  if (parts.length === 3) {
    result.push(parts[1]);
  }
  if (parts.length > 3) {
    parts.shift();
    parts.pop();
    result = parts;
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```